# Convergence limit of truncated convergent series.

Tags: sequences-and-series

In general if 
$$S={\Sigma}_n^\infty a_n $$

converges, under what circumstnces can a convergence exist for partial/truncated series sum :

$$ Sn=\Sigma_1 ^n a_k, \quad k\lt n  ?$$

Also can there be a closed form expression for this partial series?

I am not quite familiar in the area, a short guiding comment/answer would suffice. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean: If $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges, can a closed-form expression for $s_n = \sum_{k=1}^n a_k$ always be found?

Comment: Yes,thanks. That is the ( is too general ?) situation I wanted to be able to ask about.